# Single File publish doesn't work with a WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I have a simple WPF app that I want to publish as a single exe file. I invoke the command:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

In the end, I get the `exe` and `pdb` files. When I try to run the `exe`, the cursor turns into "loading" state for a few seconds and... that's it. The app doesn't run. There's no error, it just doesn't start.
When I deploy the app without the "single file" option, the app works fine.

I'm using .NET Core 3.1.401

What is wrong?

//EDIT

Dependency Walker logs (I published app in x86 and used x86 Dependency Walker):

```
Started "ADP.WPFUI.EXE" (process 0x40FC) at address 0x00860000 by thread 1.  Cannot hook module.
Loaded "NTDLL.DLL" at address 0x77C20000 by thread 1.  Cannot hook module.
Loaded "KERNEL32.DLL" at address 0x759C0000 by thread 1.  Cannot hook module.
Loaded "KERNELBASE.DLL" at address 0x75BC0000 by thread 1.  Cannot hook module.
DllMain(0x75BC0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "KERNELBASE.DLL" called by thread 1.
DllMain(0x75BC0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "KERNELBASE.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.
DllMain(0x759C0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "KERNEL32.DLL" called by thread 1.
DllMain(0x759C0000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "KERNEL32.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.
Injected "DEPENDS.DLL" at address 0x08370000 by thread 1.
DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "DEPENDS.DLL" called by thread 1.
DllMain(0x08370000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "DEPENDS.DLL" returned 1 (0x1) by thread 1.
Second chance exception 0xC0000005 (Access Violation) occurred at address 0x707AE0E0 by thread 1.
Exited "ADP.WPFUI.EXE" (process 0x40FC) with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) by thread 1.
```

Comment: Have you tried publishing using the VS UI?

Comment: It [might take a while](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/) for it to start. What's your application doing? Did you try to publish a blank app created using the default template?

Comment: I tried with VS. Same result. @mm8 It didn't start until now, so I assume it doesn't work :)  I just tried to publish a blank app, as you suggested, and it works! I wonder, what is the issue with my app? My app is mostly doing HTTP requests. It uses Dependency Injection, has some NuGet dependencies (only from nuget.org, no custom feeds there). Other than that it is a rather normal WPF app.

Comment: "Other than that.."? Since it works with a blank app, it's obviously something wrong with the code you have written.

Comment: try dependency walker to see which dll fails to load, DI could be a problem only if you used p:PublishTrimmed option

Comment: @mm8 Since the app starts completely fine when the option PublishSingleFile is false, I don't really think the issue is on my side.

Comment: @Loreno: Please provide the minimal amount of code required to reproduce your issue when asking a question on SO.

Comment: @Bizhan I run dependency walker. The output is added to the question. I didn't use the Trimmed option.

Comment: looks like it cannot hook ADP.WPFUI.EXE for some reason, try to reproduce it in another project with minimal dependencies, and see which dependency (or content file) is giving you the issue. or you can report it to netcore on github

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem for both ".NET Core 3.1" and ".NET Core 5.0".

First, try having `-c Release` set before `-r win-x64`. I don't know why it is so, but that is what worked for me. So, for your example code, what it need to be is:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

What going on in your code-behind can also be the cause of the problem. For myself, it was the event-handler that reached out to the buttons in the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pdb-file is not packaged in the executable.

For me including this line (either in the build file or publish profile) made it work:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSymbolsInSingleFile>true</IncludeSymbolsInSingleFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

see:
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10523#issuecomment-535619277

You can check the source of the error in the windows EventViewer.
An error for a missing pdb-file looks like this:

```
Description: A .NET Core application failed.
Application: program.exe
Path: C:\path\to\program.exe
Message: Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (program.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.runtime', version: '2.0.1'
    path: 'runtimes/win-x64/native/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.pdb'
```